# Macro to mark email as read and move to folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm a complete beginner with macros in Outlook, but I would like to create a macro which marks an email as read, and moves it to a specific folder.  Any help most welcome. I have searched to see if this precise request has been answered elsewhere, but haven't been successful.

Many thanks,
Bevis

Comment: You don't need a macro. There's a built-in Quick Action that does this exact thing.

Answer (score 0):

Note, in Outlook you can create a rule or quick action to get the job done.

If you decide to go with VBA macros you need to set up the [UnRead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.unread) property and call the [Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.move) method to move the item to the required folder. You may find the [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office) article helpful.